# Object equality(object referece "==")

Tags: java, string, object, operators, equality

I have written this code in eclipse:

`String[] s = {"a","b"};`
`String d = "a";`
`System.out.println(s[0]==d);`

and it is giving "true" as output.

"==" checks for object reference, if both object refer to same object, but here in this case object "d" refers to different object and "s[0]" to different, then how come they are equal.

Comment: Do some home work before asking.

Comment: @almasshaikh am looking for answer not comment.

Comment: Answer lies in comment. IF you could have googled and you would have got above link which is why your question is marked as duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

`"a"` will have been created in the string pool used by the JVM.

As an optimisation only one instance of that string will have been created. Java can do this since strings are *immutable*. That's why the references are referencing the same underlying object, so in this particular instances, the references compare equal.